# set cookies in parent directory php

Tags: php, cookies

My directory structure is as follows:

- login/login.php
- homepage.php

How can i set cookies from login.php in the parent directory so that I can use them in homepage.php.

I've tried `setcookie("userid",$row["userid"],time()+3600,"../");` to set cookie and `print_r($_COOKIE);` in homepage.php doesn't show any cookies

Comment: does it saved in the browser? check the settings to see if it is there.

Comment: yes its there in login.php but not in homepage.php

Comment: in the browser? you know settings/content/cookies/

Comment: @jycr753 yes, its there but in /login directory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `/` as the cookie path. That way your cookie will be available to your entire domain.

```
setcookie('userid', $row['userid'], time() + 3600, '/');
```

Regardless of where you set it and where you retrieve it, it will be available via `$_COOKIE['userid']`.